# In a Platonic utilitarianism, would the only commandment be, "Contemplate the Form of Happiness"?

Tags: plato, utilitarianism, utility

Suppose that the Form of Happiness were the most happiness-bringing entity possible, i.e. that Platonic contemplation of this Form would cause the greatest happiness possible for any entity (including the Forms-as-"alive"). No weighing of other outcomes, no comparison of different people's capacities for pleasure or joy: would these follow? And if anyone's individual contemplation of this Form brought perfect *ananda* unto them, would we even be called to sum the bliss of the masses, to judge an action as bringing about the greatest happiness? Or would *any* contemplation of the Form be a maximum in this system?

Comment: The perfect *ananda* of any individual is not the ananda of the contemplation of this Form of Happiness but the contemplation of this single Form of Happiness itself...